# Spread sheet file reading into database in Perl script

Tags: perl, spreadsheet, import-from-excel

I am new to perl. I need to read the excel file and insert into Database.. Here is my trial code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DBI;
use warnings;
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=afscp;host=135.75.60.120;    mysql_socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock","blrdev_rw","W.mZk8", {'RaiseError'  => 1});
my $insert_table_2= $dbh->prepare(q{INSERT INTO employee_perl  (emp_id,first_nm,last_nm,team_code) VALUES (?, ?,?,?)}) or die $dbh->errstr;
open (FILE, "Excel/Book1.xls") or die "Couldn't read file: $!"; 

while (<FILE>)
    {
        chomp;
        my @fields = split(',', $_);

        my $emp_id = shift(@fields);
        my $fname = shift(@fields);
        my $lname = shift(@fields);
       my $team_code = shift(@fields);      
       $insert_table_2->execute($emp_id,$fname,$lname,$team_code) or   die        $dbh->errstr;
    }

close (FILE);  
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: xls is a binary format - you will need sth like http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm to read the binary format.

Comment: What platform are you on? You can drive Excel using `Win32::OLE`. You can  also _probably_ unpick an `xlsx` because that's a zip file holding XML.

Answer (score 1):

CPAN module `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` is your friend to read excel.
From doc :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');
if ( !defined $workbook )
{
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() )
{
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max )
    {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max )
        {
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";
            print "Unformatted = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried above code  I am getting following error :                                        Can't locate Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at excel.pl line 3.

Comment: Yes. Spreadsheet::ParseExcel is a CPAN module. You'll need to install it. Also, you might consider upgrading your version of Perl. 5.8.8 was released nine years ago. The current version is 5.20.

Comment: It means you don't have installed Spreadsheet::ParseExcel module in your system. Have a look on this how to install perl modules: http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably benefit from the good work shared on CPAN for that: [enter link description here](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Excel&size=20). If you are using a GNU/Linux OS you may check what modules are available as compiled packages (i.e. you can install using aptitude or emerge or MacPorts for example).

Also you'd need to consider that Excel is a software supporting several spreadsheet formats, with several versions for each.

In some business scenarios you may consider connecting your spreadsheets to some RDBMS server so the excel files turns into a frontend to a shared data store.